# perfectly normal space

Tags: general-topology

If $X$ is a Hausdorff topological space, we say that $X$ is perfectly normal if, for every closed set $A$, there exists a continuous function $f_A:X\rightarrow[0,1]$ such that $f_A^{-1}(0)=A$.

Prove that perfectly normal spaces are normal.

My effort:
Suppose $A$ and $B$ are two disjoint closed set. Define $g=\frac{f_A}{f_A+f_B}$. $g(x)=0$ if and only if $x\in A$, and $g(x)=1$ if and only if $x\in B$.

As long as I can prove $g:X\rightarrow [0,1]$ is continuous, I am done. But I do not know how to show it is continuous.

Comment: Your approach is correct. It is a basic theorem that the sum $u + v$ of real-valued continous functions $u, v : X \to \mathbb R$ is continuous and, provided $v(x) \ne 0$ on $X$, also the quotient $\frac{u}{v}$ is continuous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way can be to see your map $g$ as the following composition

$g=G\circ (f_A,f_B)$ where

$(f_A,f_B): X\to [0,1]\times [0,1]$

and

$G: E\subseteq [0,1]\times [0,1]\to [0,1]$

where $E=\{(x,y): x\neq 0 \textit{ or } y\neq 0\}$

And the map is $G(x,y):= \frac{x}{x+y}$

that is continuos on its domain. This map is continuos for the same reasoning of Kavi Rama Murthy.

Answer (score 0):

$f_A(x)+f_B(x) \geq 0$ and $f_A(x)+f_B(x) = 0$ if and only if $f_A(x)=f_B(x)=0$ if and only if $x \in A$ and $x\in B$ which is impossible. Hence $g$ is the ratio of two continuous functions in which the denominator never vanishes. This implies that $g$ is continuous.